# changing the location of a component in different states

Tags: components, flex4.5

Hello my good people of stackOverflow,

Recently, i was building a component where a certain dropDownList component with id = languageCombo, has to be relocated dynamically as the states change..here is the code for the two states: initial and chaingrp. i want the dropDownList component to change from one position X in the initial state to another position X = 500 in the tree_changeHandler function when the chaingrp state is called but the dropDownList component doesn't change. Could anyone point me to what the problem could be?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     xmlns:components="components.*"
     xmlns:searchComponents="searchComponents.*"
     minHeight="500" minWidth="500">


<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="SearchClick", type="eventClass.SelectedTableEvent")]
</fx:Metadata>



<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import eventClass.SelectedTableEvent;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        import mx.events.TreeEvent;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        namespace simo="http://www.simo-project.org/simo";
        [Bindable]
        public var parentXmlCopy:XML;
        [Bindable]
        public var treeXml:XML;
        [Bindable]
        private var newXml:XML;
        private var transferredname:String;
        public var  modelType:String;
        public var selectedModelchainIndex:int;
        public var selectedTaskIndex:int;





        public function set variables(_xml:XML):void{
            parentXmlCopy = _xml;   
        }

        private function languageChange(event:Event):void{
            trace("languageChange");
            var cb:DropDownList=event.target as DropDownList;
            var temp:Object=cb.selectedItem;


            var chain:Array=[];
            for (var i:int=0; i < cb.dataProvider.length; i++)
            {
                if(cb.dataProvider[i].label == temp.label)
                {
                    chain.push(cb.dataProvider[i].locale);
                    resourceManager.localeChain=chain;
                }
            }

        }






        protected function tree_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            use namespace simo;
            var selectedItem:XML;

            transferredname = tree.selectedItem.localName();

            switch (transferredname){

                case "chain_group" : currentState = "chaingroup";
                 languageCombo.X = 500;

                 selectedItem = XML(tree.selectedItem);

                 trace(selectedItem);

                 this.chainGrpId.displayChainGrp(selectedItem);
                break;

            }

        }


            private function treeLabel(item:Object):String
            {

            return item.localName();        
        }



    ]]>
</fx:Script>



<s:states>
    <s:State name="initial"/>
    <s:State name="chaingroup"/>

</s:states>

    <s:HGroup><!--overall outer Hgroup-->
    <s:HGroup gap="8">
        <s:HGroup gap="5">
            <s:VGroup  height="460" paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="5">
                <s:HGroup gap="3">
                    <searchComponents:AutoComplete/>
                    <s:Button 
                        id="searchBT" 
                        height="24" 
                        width="24" 
                        skinClass="skins.searchBTskin"/>
                </s:HGroup>
                <s:List id="treeDP" height="120" width="180" labelField="@name"
                        change="treeDP_changeHandler(event)">
                    <s:dataProvider>
                        <s:XMLListCollection source="{parentXmlCopy.children()}" />
                    </s:dataProvider>
                </s:List>
                <s:Button id="delListBT" label="delList"/>
                <s:HGroup gap="70">
                    <s:Button 
                        id="backBT"
                        label="back"
                        height="24" 
                        width="24" 
                        />
                    <s:Button 
                        id="nextBT"
                        label="next"
                        height="24" 
                        width="24" 
                        />

                </s:HGroup>


                <mx:Tree id="tree" dataProvider="{treeXml}" labelField="{treeXml.localName()}"
                         top="72" left="50" labelFunction="treeLabel"
                         maxHorizontalScrollPosition="20"
                         maxVerticalScrollPosition="10"
                         showRoot="true"
                         change="tree_changeHandler(event)"
                         height="225" width="180"/>


                <s:Button id="delTreeBT" label="delTree"/>
            </s:VGroup>




            <s:Group includeIn="chaingroup/>

        </s:HGroup>

    </s:HGroup>

<s:HGroup paddingLeft="200" paddingTop="5"
          x.modelOperation="-38" y.modelOperation="-22" width.modelOperation="737"
          x.modelPrediction="-18" y.modelPrediction="-20">
    <s:DropDownList id="languageCombo" width="150" change="languageChange(event)" includeIn="initial"
                    dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection([{locale:'fi_FI',label:'Suomi'}, {locale:'en_US', label:'English'}])}"
                    prompt="{resourceManager.getString('modelChainUI','lang')}"
                    x.chaingroup="900"
                    x.condition="900"
                    x.modelchain="900"
                    x.task="900"/>
</s:HGroup>
    </s:HGroup><!--overall hgroup ends here!-->

<s:VGroup gap="5" paddingLeft="10"
          x.chaingroup="144" y.chaingroup="-69" height.chaingroup="148">
    <components:ChainGroup id="chainGrpId" includeIn="chaingroup"/>
    </s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `languageCombo` is within `HGroup`. `HGroup` is a container with horizontal layout. Horizontal layout doesn't consider any `x` and `y` coordinates of children (because of it is horizontal layout).

Maybe it better to use simple `Group` (taking in mind your `HGroup` has only one child — so horizontal layout hasn't sense)?

Comment: i have used the HGroup so i can horizontally allign the dropDownList component horizontally from the tree component. if i have to use Group, i still need to indicate somehow where exactly to place the dropDownList component. with the X and Y axis, it doesnt really fix properly. is there anyway i could still use the HGroup and still be able to move the location between states?

Comment: I mean closest to the drop down `HGroup` which starts with `<s:HGroup paddingLeft="200" paddingTop="5"`.

Comment: yeah i know. but if take that HGroup away and just use a <s:Group> component, then the alignment wont be that good. could take it away but am not sure if it will still solve the location changes..would have preferred it's possible to still change the dropDownList location using the HGroup component.

Comment: You can put `Spacer` in your `HGroup` and include/exclude it in states.

Comment: i just took the HGroup away..so that i have a <s:Group/> surrounding the dropDownList component and then did the languageCombo.X = 500; in the tree_Handler() event when the state is changed to chainGrp but the dropDownList component is still invisible in the chainGrp state

Comment: Try to play with [`clipAndEnableScrolling` flag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#clipAndEnableScrolling).